# Suppose $G/H$ Is isomorphic to $K$ , then is $G/K$ is isomorphic to $H$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and $ H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$.

Suppose $G/H$ is isomorphic to $K$, then $G/K$ is isomorphic to $H$ ?

If $G $ is a finite group, I came up with an counter example.

Let $G=\{±1,±I,±j,±k\}$　and $H=\{±1,±I\}, K=\{±1\}$
We can easily check $G/H$ is isomorphic to $K$ although  $G/K$ is Klein four group and not isomorphic to $H$.

But if $G$ is a infinite group, are there any counterexamples?

I couldn't find counterexample but cannot prove $G/K$ is isomorphic to $H$ either.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take $G=\mathbb{Z}^2$, $H=0\times \mathbb{Z}$ and $K=0\times 2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $H\simeq K\simeq \mathbb{Z}$.

You can check that $G/H\simeq \mathbb{Z}\simeq K$, but $G/K\simeq \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\not\simeq H$.